# Retrieving hierarchy in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, recursive-query

I have a table in database

```
EmployeeID                TeamLeadID
2                          1
3                          2
4                          3
5                          NULL
1                          NULL
6                          1
7                          2
8                          3
```

Now what I want is to retrieve all the `TeamLeadsID` (i.e all the upper hierarchy) for a given `EmployeeID`

- For `EmployeeID = 2` I should get ans 1 (because we don't have `TeamleadID` for `EmployeeId = 1`)
- For `EmployeeID = 4` I should get 3,2 and 1 (because 4->Teamlead is 3, 3 -> Teamlead is 2, 2 -> TeamLead is 1)
- Likewise for `EmployeeID = 7` I should get 2 and 1 only

while for 5 & 1 it should be Null as clearly seen from the table itself

Comment: Yes - nice - and what's **your effort** so far? What do you have - where are you stuck? This is not a **gimme ze codez** site that'll just provide code - you need to **show some effort yourself** first !

Comment: You first need to write some code, like a recursive CTE. We can then help you if you cannot make it work properly.

Comment: This is a really basic recursive CTE case, you shouldn't have any trouble in finding examples

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-server+recursive-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimum effort would be:

- Go to Google and search for **SQL Server recursive CTE tutorial**: [https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+recursive+cte+tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql%20server%20recursive%20cte%20tutorial)
- Open and read 1st link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx
- Write a query such as:

  ```
  Declare @EmployeeID int = 4

  ; with list(EmployeeID, TeamLeadID) as (
      Select EmployeeID, TeamLeadID From Employees Where EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
      Union All
      Select e.EmployeeID, e.TeamLeadID From Employees E
          Inner Join list l On l.TeamLeadID = E.EmployeeID
      Where E.TeamLeadID is not NULL
  )
  Select TeamLeadID From list
  ```